# Validate JavaScript syntax in IDE (Editor)?

Tags: javascript, ide

Are there any JavaScript editors that can validate JavaScript syntax on the fly? Things like missing brackets, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I like to use `emacs` with [`flymake`](http://flymake.sourceforge.net/), which can [use `Spidermonkey`, `JsLint` or `Rhino` to do the validation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeJavaScript).  This does the sort of on the fly syntax checking I think you are after. If you want a liberal validation, you might want to use `Spidermonkey` as it is the execution engine from firefox, so it will reject anything firefox rejects.  If you want something a little stricter, Crockford's `JsLint` enforces good style.[image: flymake with spidermonkey]
<sub>(source: [mnemonikk.org](http://mnemonikk.org/images/emacs-flymake-spidermonkey.png))</sub>

Emacs is not for everyone however.  If you prefer something point-and-click, you might want to check out [IntelliJ's `IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/).  It can do on the fly syntax checking, along with a raft of other features.  Sadly, javascript support is not available in the free version.

[image: IntelliJ's javascript syntax checking]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/60/JS_Error_highlighting.gif))</sub>

A free alternative to IntelliJ is [`Netbeans`](https://netbeans.org/), which [purports to offer the same javascript functionality](https://web.archive.org/web/20100813193501/http://netbeans.org:80/kb/61/ide/javascript-editor.html) baked into the core.  I don't have experience with it, but it is free, open source, and reputedly improving in recent versions
[netbean's javascript syntax highlighting http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/61/ide/javascript/background_parser.png](http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/61/ide/javascript/background_parser.png)

**If you're a Windows or ASP.NET type developer** you might be more interested in [Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20111013105002/http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web).  It [supports this features](https://web.archive.org/web/20160511055216/http://www.microsoft.com:80/web/platform/tools-developer.aspx), and probably has better support for ASP.NET development than the other tools I've mentioned.

Comment: how long did it take you to configure emacs to work the way you wanted it?

Comment: @Andrew About half an hour :(

Comment: that's actually a lot better than I was expecting. If I could pull that off, I'd consider it a resounding success. I will try this out.

Comment: I also found this helpful: http://mnemonikk.org/2008/05/06/live-syntax-checking-javascript-with-emacs/

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA's excellent JavaScript support is also present in RubyMine and PhpStorm and WebStorm.

Answer (score 4):

You can go grab Javascript Lint then do exactly what you want and use whatever editor you want:

Javascript Lint - http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm

Comment: Love it, but it's not an IDE :P

Answer (score 2):

I use Komodo Edit from Activestate. It validates, has code completion, brace matching, etc., and not just for Javascript.

Edit: BTW I have a macro in Komodo Edit that calls JS_Beautify and does a spectacular job.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse (or it's web specialized form  Aptana) and Netbeans offer syntax checking on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Visual Web Developer Express 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629125200/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/12/visual-web-developer-2010-express-has-arrived.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea of validating your .js with c# in VS http://madskristensen.net/post/Verify-JavaScript-syntax-using-C.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, [the JSDT project](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) provides a JavaScript nature. Like most of Eclipse's language natures, it provides a context engine with realtime validation, syntax highlighting, completion, etc.

Comment: [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) is built on Eclipse and is aimed at generic web, rails and Adobe Air development. I'm personally not partial to Eclipse, but Aptana works pretty well.